# How to get value if a input fields defined as ClientIDMode="Static"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I defined input control on webform as

```
 <input type="text" id="Amount1" class="auto-sum"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
```

and on runtime  it appears as below.

`<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Amount1" id="Amount1" class="auto-sum" type="text">`

When i try to get the value from CodeBehind i can see the control name

i get nothing as Amount. how to get value of such input field

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
TextBox1.Text = Amount1.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using `ClientIDMode="Static"`. This can cause problems later on. Especially since you seem to be using `ContentPlaceHolder`, which would indicate a Master Page.

Consider the following. You add `TextBox1` with a static ID on the Master Page, some time later you do the same on a Page which uses a Master Page. You now have two elements on the page with ID `TextBox1`, instead of `ctl00$TextBox1` and `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox1`.

If you need it for Client side purposes, you can always use `TextBox1.ClientID`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Amount1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-sum"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("<%= Amount1.ClientID %>").value = "It works!";
</script>
```